# Click-triggered scrollTop takes random amount of time to fire

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, scrolltop

I have a comment section which automatically scrolls into view when you scroll it (using jQuery `scrollTop`), and then a button which scrolls you back up when you click it. The first scrolling action always runs perfectly, but the second scrolling action takes a seemingly random amount of time to occur after the button is pressed.

A live demonstration can be found here: [www.rouvou.com/KanyeWest](http://www.rouvou.com/pages/Kanye%20West). Go down to the comment section, and scroll it to fire the first jquery scroll. Then click the "Back" button to fire the second scroll. It might work instantly the first few times you try it, but if you do it enough, it should be delayed eventually.

**html**

```
<div id="comment-section">
  <div id="comment-background-up">BACK</div>
  <div id="good_comments"><!--CONTENT--></div>  
  <div id="bad_comments"><!--CONTENT--></div>
</div>
```

**jquery**

```
$("#good_comments").scroll(function() {
  $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $("#good_comments").offset().top
  }, 700);
  $("#comment-background-up").fadeIn(200);
});
$("#bad_comments").scroll(function() {
  $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $("#bad_comments").offset().top
  }, 700);
  $("#comment-background-up").fadeIn(200);
});
$("#comment-background-up").click(function() {
  $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $("#randomajax").offset().top
  }, 700);
  $(this).fadeOut(200);
});
```

Does anyone know what could be causing this delay?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose this is happening because jQuery daisy-chains the animations. And you initiate the animation on **every** scroll. So the much you scroll, the more 700ms animations "pile up", hence your go back animation waiting for them all to finish.

It would probably be best to update your code to avoid chained scrollTop animations on the body.

However, for now you could fix this by using jQuery's [stop](https://api.jquery.com/stop/) function. I.e.:

```
$("#comment-background-up").click(function() {
  $('html, body').stop(true, true).animate({
      scrollTop: $("#randomajax").offset().top
  }, 700);
  $(this).fadeOut(200);
});
```

Comment: Wow, thanks, I would have never figured that out! Do you know how I could avoid chaining the scrollTops though?

Comment: Maybe check the scrollTop parameter of the document and if it's already in the right place, do not initiate the animation.